# find() does not recognize my custom iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I wrote a custom iterator named Text_Iterator for a simple text editor. However, STL algorithms such as find() would not recognize it as a legitimate iterator.

My code is:

```
using Line = std::vector<char>;

class Text_iterator {
    std::list<Line>::iterator ln;
    Line::iterator pos;

public:
    Text_iterator(std::list<Line>::iterator ll, Line::iterator pp)
        : ln{ll}, pos{pp} {}

    char& operator*() { return *pos; }
    Text_iterator& operator++();
    Text_iterator& operator--();

    bool operator==(const Text_iterator& other) const 
    {
        return (ln == other.ln && pos == other.pos);
    }
    bool operator!=(const Text_iterator& other) const
    {
        return (!(*this == other));
    }
};
```

When I try to use this iterator in an algorithm, for example in find(), I get the following error:

```
1>...\xutility(861,56): error C2794: 'value_type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=Text_iterator
1>        ]
```

Why would it not register as a legitimate iterator?

Edit: Works with the following additional declarations:

```
using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
using value_type = char;
using pointer = char*;
using reference = char&;
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy all the STL requirements. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator

Comment: @Evg `std::find()` works with iterators that satisfy [*InputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) or [*ForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), it does not require *BidirectionalIterator*.

Comment: Because it's not a legitimate iterator. Legitimate iterators must have specific members that specify the iterator's properties. They should be explained in textbooks covering advanced C++ template topics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, but from `operator++()` and `operator--()` in OP's code I guess their intent is to define a bidirectional iterator.

Comment: Also see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits, you probably also need to declare `difference_type` etc..

Comment: @Evg Since OP uses a  `std::list<Line>::iterator ln;`, I assume you mean to say that bidirectional and list iterators are incompatible right?

Comment: I am following Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++". What is interesting to me is that while this is a beginner level book, the author does not mention any of the requirements you refer to, and gives the impression that this definition would automatically satisfy the find() requirements.

Comment: @berkeozgur which *edition* of the book are you using, though?  A lot has changed since the first edition was first published.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Second Edition, which was published in 2014. (pages 734-741) I've tried adding a value_type before posting the question, but it didn't seem to work. This makes sense since you mentioned that there were more than one required members. I am just surprised that this is much more complicated than the author indicates.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's `Text_iterator` that is passed into `std::find()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is complaining that [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) does not have a `value_type` member when applied to your `Text_iterator` class.

Your class's `operator*` is returning a `char&`, but your class does not have a `value_type` member that aliases `char`, eg:

```
class Text_iterator {
    ...

public:
    typedef char value_type;
    // or: using value_type = char;
    // or: typedef std::iterator_traits<Line::iterator>::value_type value_type;
    // or: using value_type = st::iterator_traits<Line::iterator>::value_type;
    ...
};
```

`std::find()` only works with iterators that satisfy the requirements of [*InputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) or [*ForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).

So, you need to either

- add the required members to your class (there are several more than just `value_type`) so the default `std::iterator_traits` can find them.
- specialize [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for your class.

Comment: If it's not such a burden, what exactly would I need to add to my definition to make it work? I read the links you've shared but for someone who is relatively new to C++, they seem a little obscure.

Comment: The 2 requirements pages I linked to explain all of the operators and members you need to implement for your class

Comment: I will study them in more detail. Thank you for your time. I may bother you later if I get stuck again, if its okay. :)

Comment: [Writing a custom iterator in modern C++](https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp)